# Drop packets after NAT in iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to rate limit traffic to a certain client behind the NAT (using hashlimit combined with DROP target) using iptables rule but due to my rudimentary knowledge of this area, I'm not sure which table and which chain I'm supposed to add this rule in or whether this is at possible.

This exact scenario has been [asked before](https://serverfault.com/questions/523589/is-there-any-way-to-filter-packets-eg-by-iptables-after-routing-is-complete) but the answer does not give any concrete solutions.

Comment: I've tried adding a rule to FORWARD chain in filter table (ie `-I FORWARD 1 -d 192.0.0.0/24 -j DROP`). Without `-d`, I achieve filtering, but as I understand it, both directions are filtered. I only want packets destined for the NAT clients to be filtered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the `FORWARD` chain in the `filter` table. But you really ought to be applying the filter much sooner.

Why would the packet be forwarded to that client in the first place? From the way the question is worded, I assume the client is using a RFC 1918/4193/6598 address, so the packet could not be targeted directly at that client.

Either there must be a `nat` rule, which directs the packet to that client, or there must be an entry in the connection table.

A `nat` rule to forward a packet to a specific client followed by a `filter` rule to reject the packet makes no sense. If this was the case, you could remove both rules and achieve the same result in a much less error prone way.

If on the other hand the packet was forwarded due to an entry in the connection table, then that entry would have been created by an earlier packet. But then you should have rejected the earlier packet such that the connection table entry never was created. In other words, reject outgoing packets from that specific client. This can also be done in the `FORWARD` chain the `filter` table.

Comment: I see. I'd simplified my question. I'm actually trying to rate limit a specific IP (using hashlimit), so not all packets are dropped.